# Puzzled by DOM behavior dynamically loaded select = undefined

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Below is the following code that works perfectly for dynamic loading of a select drop down. The code is called in the documents ready function to pre-load data into a page. The code works just fine. However, I got puzzled over the fact that it seems "undefined" in the DOM. ie.. .change event etc...when I attempt to select a value....

In the HTML, the  is set simply:

```
<select id="optionsChaa" name="chaa_id" class="largewidth"></select>
```

The jquery code is as follows. It works. Feel free to use it in your codes

```
var optionsValues = '<select id="optionsChaa" name="chaa_id" class="largewidth">';
                optionsValues += '<option value=""></option>';
                $.each(result, function() {
                    optionsValues += '<option value="' + this.chaa_id.val + '">' + this.chaa_name + '</option>';
                });
                optionsValues += '</select>';

                var options = $('#optionsChaa');
                options.replaceWith(optionsValues);

                $('#optionsChaa').change(function() {

                   // Alert returns undefined...

                    alert($(this).val() );

                });
```

So why is it "undefined" after the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's something wrong with the `this.chaa_id.val` part. In `each`, "this" refers to the "current" element (i.e. a member of the `results` array).

Answer (score 1):

Could you show what's in your `result` variable?

I tried your code setting `result` as:

```
var result = [
    { 'chaa_id' : { 'val' : 1 }, 'chaa_name' : 'name1'},
    { 'chaa_id' : { 'val' : 2 }, 'chaa_name' : 'name2'}
]
```

And the `alert()` seems to work.

Comment: It comes back from an List<> that has been parsed by json. Each [0],[1],[2]. Each number has three properties __type, chaa_id, chaa_name.  The __type is "CHAAInfo" which is a collection property from .NET (get,set etc)

Comment: The problem was solved. It was my fault. Take a look at the line this.chaa_id.val - the word .val should not be in there. I do apologize. Please feel free to download a baseball bat and find me...